# How to send data from directive to parent controller in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am trying to control the html based on the value inside directive.

I have a html like this:

```
//myCtrl.isLoad was set to false
<img ng-src="{{myCtrl.url}}" imageonload></img>
<div ng-if="myCtrl.isLoad">Show me</div>
```

Directive:

```
 angular.module('myApp')
        .directive('imageonload', imageonloadFunction);

    function imageonloadFunction() {
        var directive = {
            'link': link,                
            'restrict': 'A'
        };

        return directive;
    }

    function link($scope, element, attrs) {
        some other codes..        
        //Do something if the condition is met
        //and change myCtrl.isLoad = true so 
        //<div ng-if="myCtrl.isLoad">Show me</div>  
        //will show
    }
```

I am not sure the best way to bind the directive data to the parent. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have to pass the `myCtrl.isLoad` variable to the directive... `<img ng-src="{{myCtrl.url}}" imageonload is-load="myCtrl.isLoad"></img>
<div ng-if="myCtrl.isLoad">Show me</div> `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just bind the controller property to the directive.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
        .directive('imageonload', imageonloadFunction);

    function imageonloadFunction() {
        var directive = {
            'link': link,
            'scope': {
              'isLoad': '='
            },
            'restrict': 'A'
        };

        return directive;
    }

    function link($scope, element, attrs) {
      $scope.isLoad = true;
        //Do something if the condition is met
        //and change myCtrl.isLoad = true so 
        //<div ng-if="myCtrl.isLoad">Show me</div>  
        //will show
    }
```

```html
//myCtrl.isLoad was set to false
<img ng-src="{{myCtrl.url}}" imageonload is-load="myCtrl.isLoad"></img>
<div ng-if="myCtrl.isLoad">Show me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Display Loader When image load.

In HTML:

```
<img src="img/loading.gif" imageload="{{myCtrl.url}}">
```

Directive :

```
.directive('imageload', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                imageload: '@'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.one('load', function() {
                    element.attr('src', scope.imageload);

                });
            }
        };
    })
```